# Load shell configuration file when starting container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

## Problem

I want to load a custom `.zshrc` whenever I enter the docker container with `docker run -it container_name` given that the `.zshrc` file is already in the container.

## Description

I have a Dockerfile with the following structure:

```
FROM archlinux:latest

# Install things...
# Install zsh & oh-my-zsh
# Retrieve custom .zshrc from a repository and place it at ~/.zshrc
# Clone extensions for oh-my-zsh

# Run zsh on container start
CMD [ "zsh" ]
```

This all works. If I enter the container I can see that my custom `.zshrc` file is where it's supposed to be and if I run `source ~/.zshrc` it gets loaded and all extensions work.

## Attempt

I have tried sourcing the configuration file directly in the `CMD` step but it cannot find the specified file. Updated line looks as follows:
`CMD [ "zsh && source ~/.zshrc" ]`

I know this might not be the intended way of using docker containers but it's more of a learning experience and I wanted to see if it could be done.

Comment: You can mapping your directory. https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: I don't really understand how that would work. Doesn't that mean I have to have the file locally on my host machine? I was wondering if I could use the already cloned file inside the docker container.

Comment: @alexHexan : I don't have enough knowledge about docker, but can you set in the docker configuration an environment variable, which is then established before zsh starts? If you set the varialble `ZDOTDIR`, it must name a directory, and the .zshrc is then sourced from that directory instead from `$HOME`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem wasn't fully with the `Dockerfile`. Yes as @Exadra37 mentioned `CMD [ "zsh && source ~/.zshrc" ]` did not work because of the execution order. However, the problem was with my `.zshrc` configuration.

After testing it again on my own machine I realized it wasn't loading automatically either.

## Conclusion

`CMD [ "/bin/zsh" ]` as the last row in my Dockerfile automatically loads the `.zshrc` file located at `/root/.zshrc`, I just had to make sure my configuration file was written properly.

Answer (score 2):

### DOCKERFILE

You need to add the command `chsh -s /path/to/shell` in order to add the ZSH shell as the default for the user in the container:

```
FROM archlinux:latest

# Install things...
# Install zsh & oh-my-zsh
# Retrieve custom .zshrc from a repository and place it at ~/.zshrc
# Clone extensions for oh-my-zsh

# Make ZSH the default shell for the current user in the container
# To check that the shell was indeed added: `chsh -l` and you should see it in the  list.
RUN chsh -s ~/.zshrc

# Run zsh on container start
CMD [ "zsh" ]
```

### OTHER APPROACHES

#### Dockerfile CMD

This does not work, because the execution order:

```
CMD [ "zsh && source ~/.zshrc" ]
```

But this should work(not tested):

```
# using `root` user, adjust as needed for your case
CMD [ "source /root/.zshrc", "zsh"]
```

#### Docker Entrypoint

If you don't want to add it to the Dockerfile then use it in as the entrypoint:

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint "chsh -s /root/.zshrc" image-name
```

Note that the example assumes the user in the container is `root`, please adjust accordingly your case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should update the content of `$HOME/.profile`. Here's an example.

The .profile:

```sh
source .zshrc
```

The .zshrc:

```sh
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
echo "I'm getting executed!!!!"
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt update \
    && apt install -yyq zsh curl git

RUN sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"

COPY .profile /root/.profile
COPY .zshrc /root/.zshrc

CMD ["zsh"]
```

Then you can try it out with

```sh
docker build -t zsh:latest .
docker run --rm -it zsh:latest
```

---

EDIT:

In case you don't want to COPY a new `.profile`, you can always append stuff in the existing one. e.g.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt update \
    && apt install -yyq zsh curl git

RUN sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"

RUN curl -fsSL https://www/.zshrc -o /root/.yet_another_zshrc_file \
    && echo 'source /root/.yet_another_zshrc_file' | tee -a /root/.profile

CMD ["zsh"]
```

Comment: This does work. On a side note, I'm wondering if I could do it with a file that's already inside the container. Is it possible to curl for the .profile and .zshrc files instead of copying them into the container?

Comment: sure it's possible. I've updated the answer to provide an example

Comment: nevertheless, @Exadra37 approach is cleaner